# How to call specific class and method to another python file in python 3?

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, methods

I am trying to call class and method to another python file. But, when I call the class to another python file, it will call the whole python program related to that .py file.

This is my python file having different class and its methods. file_reader.py helps to read the dataset.

**data_processing.py**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from filereader import read_data
from configuration import DATASET_PATH

data = read_data(DATASET_PATH)
scaler = StandardScaler()
'''Normalizing column and time columns to normalizedho_amount and normalized_time'''
class NormalizedColumns:

    data['normalized_amount'] = scaler.fit_transform(data['Amount'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
    data['normalized_time'] = scaler.fit_transform(data['Time'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

    print("=" * 40, "Describing normalized_amount columns ", "=" * 40)
    print(data.normalized_amount.describe())

    print("=" * 40, "Describing normalized_time columns ", "=" * 40)
    print(data.normalized_time.describe())

    '''Droping amount and time column from original dataset'''
    data = data.drop(['Time', 'Amount'], axis=1)
    print(data.head())


'''Separting features and lables'''

class NormalizedFeatures:
    def first_xdata(self):
        xData = data.iloc[:, data.columns != 'Class']  # feature
        return xData

features = NormalizedFeatures()
print(features.first_xdata().head(5))
print('Rows and columns of your new normalized dataset is :', features.first_xdata().shape)
print(features.first_xdata().columns)

print('\n')


class NormalizedLabels:
    def second_ydata(self):
        yData = data.iloc[:, data.columns == 'Class']  # lables
        return yData

labels = NormalizedLabels()

print(labels.second_ydata().head(5))
print('Rows and columns of your new normalized dataset is :', labels.second_ydata().shape)
print(labels.second_ydata().columns)
```

I want to call class NormalizedFeatures and NormalizedLabels in this python file. But this file will call whole dataprocssing.py including oversampling.py

**oversampling.py**

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

from filereader import read_data
from configuration import DATASET_PATH

from data_processing import features , labels

data = read_data(DATASET_PATH)

sm = SMOTE(random_state= 42)
x_Sampled,y_Sampled = sm.fit_sample(features.first_xdata(),labels.second_ydata().values.ravel())

Source_data_no_fraud_count = len(data[data.Class==0])
Source_data_fraud_count = len(data[data.Class==1])
print('Percentage of fraud counts in original data :{}%'.format((Source_data_fraud_count*100)/(Source_data_no_fraud_count+Source_data_fraud_count)))

Sampled_data_no_fraud_count = len(y_Sampled[y_Sampled==0])
Sampled_data_fraud_count = len(y_Sampled[y_Sampled==1])
print('Percentage of fraud counts in the new data  :{}%'.format((Sampled_data_fraud_count*100)/(Sampled_data_no_fraud_count+Sampled_data_fraud_count)))
```

**Excepted Output**

```
Percentage of fraud counts in original data:0.1727485630620034%
Percentage of fraud counts in the new data:50.0%
```

Answer (score 1):

Things in `data_proccessing.py` that you don't want executed when importing it should be guarded by an `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement. For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from filereader import read_data
from configuration import DATASET_PATH

data = read_data(DATASET_PATH)
scaler = StandardScaler()

'''Normalizing column and time columns to normalizedho_amount and normalized_time'''
class NormalizedColumns:

    data['normalized_amount'] = scaler.fit_transform(data['Amount'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
    data['normalized_time'] = scaler.fit_transform(data['Time'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

    print("=" * 40, "Describing normalized_amount columns ", "=" * 40)
    print(data.normalized_amount.describe())

    print("=" * 40, "Describing normalized_time columns ", "=" * 40)
    print(data.normalized_time.describe())

    '''Droping amount and time column from original dataset'''
    data = data.drop(['Time', 'Amount'], axis=1)
    print(data.head())


'''Separting features and lables'''

class NormalizedFeatures:
    def first_xdata(self):
        xData = data.iloc[:, data.columns != 'Class']  # feature
        return xData

if __name__ == '__main__':
    features = NormalizedFeatures()
    print(features.first_xdata().head(5))
    print('Rows and columns of your new normalized dataset is :', features.first_xdata().shape)
    print(features.first_xdata().columns)
```

This doesn't do anything about the `print` statements directly in the body of `NormalizedColumns`, but they probably shouldn't be there in the first place. Typically, the only thing you want at the top level of a `class` statement are definitions.

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like

```py
import a
```

and a.py is written as

```py
def sum(x1, x2):
    return x1 + x2
#
a = 2; b = 3;
sum(a, b)
```

importing this module will run also the lines after the #

then the best thing you can do is writing the same file as

```py
def sum(x1, x2):
    return x1 + x2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 2; b = 3;
    sum(a, b)
```

this meas that the things coming after the if, will be executed only when you execute a.py and not if the module is imported.